# Does the lack of absurdities in our universe call into question the validity of multiverse theories?

Tags: causation

Does the lack of absurdities in our universe call into question the validity of multi verse theories?

If the theories about multi verse are to be true and we have explained the immensely improbable events like the low entropy state and the fine tuning of the cosmological constant should there then not also be less probable occurrences in out universe?

Things that would be less probable than the entropy state in a multi verse (And still very much absurd) would be things like a perpetual motion machine or a flock of talking seagulls wearing bow ties and drinking wine.

Those things are are more probable than the fine tuning of the universe or the low entropy state. So if multi verses has the capacity to explain that why then are we seeing a host of more probable and absurd things in our universe?

We seem to be living in an ordered and structured universe without the absurd. Which in my mind seems to hint at some sort of intelligence giving it structure and shape... but should it?

(PS To the mods I have asked this question at the physics site as well. Seeing as this questions has elements of both physics and philosophy to it I would like an answer from both viewpoints if that is OK)

Comment: Gravity is absurd, but once you explain it and create a structured set of laws with which it agrees, it doesn't look absurd, and mostly obeys the patterns that we've observed.  Of course some times it doesn't.

Comment: for reference, here is the link to the question in the physics site - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143012/does-the-lack-of-absurdities-in-our-universe-call-into-question-the-validity-of

Comment: How about monkeys wearing bow ties and drinking wine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the theories about multi verse are to be true and we have explained the immensely improbable events like the low entropy state and the fine tuning of the cosmological constant should there then not also be less probable occurrences in out universe?

No, you're misrepresenting the concept of probability.  The improbability of our universe is like the improbability of human life -- we happen to be it, there.  But just because we notice that the vast majority of the universe, or even just our solar system, does not contain life on the order of human beings, does not mean that human beings should have all kinds of arbitrary absurd characteristics or else clearly something spooky going on.  This is like saying because I won the lottery yesterday I should continue to win all week, and if I don't, then it must be because God interfered.

Of course, perhaps humans do have all kinds of arbitrary absurd characteristics but we don't notice ;)

Comment: Last sentence is the kicker.  We only notice them with books like "Stranger In A Strange Land".  Of course all our quirks can be explained more or less if we dig deep enough, but who's got the time? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting new article on phys.org - http://phys.org/news/2014-10-parallel-worlds-collide-quantum-mechanics.html

If one accepts ipso facto that there has been or was only one universe ever, then yes it does seem ordered without the absurd. And the natural answer for many is a creator God who is looking out for us as some beneficial king or father.

If without even considering a multi-verse, simply that the universe is actually more like a pulsating wave that alternatively has an active phase and a quiescence phase, then it is not so. If there were an infinite number of universes before the present one, and an infinite number of ones to come, then perhaps the ordered rules presently observed in the current universe only occurs once in a zillion universes.

Answer (score 3):

**Absurdity is relative.**

Maybe if you live in another universe, our own would seem rather weird.

You are *used* to the *ordinary* universe so that to you it seems nothing special.

But actually there is no reason for *anything* to be what it is, at least at a certain fundamental level. 
Why physical constants have their value? Why not ten times more? Why not 2?

***There is no apparent reason for this.***

We can observe something very interesting however: **everything appears to us as consistent with some rules.**

That rules out your "absurdity" examples, like the perpetual motion machine. That's not *absurd*, that's *impossible*.

Life could be very strange and uncommon, but it's consistent with every other aspect of this universe. We obey all physics laws known until now, despite our peculiar nature of sentient living thing.

Kant would say to you that our rational way to perceive the world impedes us from knowing *absurdity*, because our own intellect reorder every perception in a self-consistent way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry perhaps we live in separate universes because mine is pretty absurd. Nothing can travel faster than the speed of light except the creation of the universe expansion ie cosmic inflation? Quantum entanglement? Strange generation of matter? My freaky mother and father :).

I mean we cope with the strangeness of the universe through levels of stupidity established by our brains. A lot of the people who have high intelligence and "are able to see all the bull sh*t" as my doctor says get sick from the absurdity of it all.